# Further action needed for non-working code that gets fixed here anyway?

Tags: discussion, site-policy, off-topic

This is in regards to [Problem in calculating prime numbers in python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29843/problem-in-calculating-prime-numbers-in-python)

As you can see from the title, the post is *only* about a problem and not a code review.  The issue at hand also seems to have been solved since one of the answers was accepted.

Would any further action be needed *if the OP doesn't want a code review*?  If it stays here, it'll just be another SO-appropriate question that came to us first.  The only real benefit from that is to set another example of off-topic questions.  But, even if it gets migrated to SO, there would not be much to add since the OP was already satisfied with the fix here.  If that's not a problem, then it could at least add to their knowledge base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing it should be enough. Migrating to SO won't help because most of these questions have already been posted on SO already like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269187/claculate-prime-numbers-in-python). Same wording, same user. It would just be waste of time for moderators to migrate them after they have been solved here.

It would be great if people don't answer them in the first place here and asked them to go to SO but that cannot be helped. After they have been answered why bother? It would serve no purpose.

Comment: I've thought so.  I've also forgotten that such a question migrated there could easily be considered a duplicate.  Yes, I too wish those questions would just be ignored until migration, but you cannot stop anyone from answering.